# Why would the loss of my neural network not be decreasing? What is wrong with my current set up? (PyTorch)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am sort of new to deep learning and have created neural nets for CIFAR-10 and MNIST datasets. I wanted to try a larger dataset with a different end goal, so I chose the Country211 dataset from Pytorch. I created the neural net (I used three convolutional layers because the input for flattening would have been massive otherwise), but it seems like the loss printed barely decreases. Am I just not running it long enough? Or is there something fundamentally wrong with my NN?

My model is below:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

# Use CUDA device
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

print(device)

# Define transform to Normalize images (input is PIL image)
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), 
                                transforms.Resize((300, 300)),
                                transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

batch_size = 64

# Define training and test set
trainset = torchvision.datasets.Country211(root='./data', split='train',
                                        transform=transform, download=True)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=0)

testset = torchvision.datasets.Country211(root='./data', split='test',
                                          download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                        shuffle=False, num_workers=0)

# classes = ()

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 8, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(8, 12, 5)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(12, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 34 * 34, 4096)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(4096, 1024)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(1024, 211)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)

        return x
```

My training loop is below:

```
net = Net()
net.to(device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
epochs = 6

for epoch in range(10):
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
        inputs, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
            print(f'[{epoch + 1}, {i + 1:5d}] loss: {running_loss / 2000:.3f}')
            running_loss = 0.0
```

My output of loss is here:

```
[1,  2000] loss: 5.352
[1,  4000] loss: 5.351
[1,  6000] loss: 5.350
[2,  2000] loss: 5.322
[2,  4000] loss: 5.320
[3,  2000] loss: 5.276
[3,  4000] loss: 5.272
[3,  6000] loss: 5.258
[4,  2000] loss: 5.211
[4,  4000] loss: 5.197
[4,  6000] loss: 5.212
[5,  4000] loss: 5.114
[5,  6000] loss: 5.140
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Actually it's decreasing, but very slowly. Try higher learning rates (e.g 0.01 or even 0.1). There could be lots of reasons but there is no global optimum hyperparameters, you need to try.

Comment: I see, I will try increasing the learning rates. As a follow up, on a large data set like this, how many epochs do neural nets usually train for? What's a good baseline to try?

Answer (score 0):

Like suggested in the comments, you may need to play around a bit with your hyperparameters: Learning Rate, Optimizer Choice, Kernel parameters, etc. In regards to how many epochs to train for: There is no magic number; a suggestion will be to track your training and validation loss curves to monitor the training.

When training loss keeps decreasing but your validation loss starts increasing, it is usually a sign of overfitting and an indication to stop training or tinker with learning rate.